# How do I find the distance an object travels while decelerating?

Tags: physics

I feel like this should be fairly obvious but I can't find any example questions in my textbook (which is usually how I figure out how to do stuff)

A 1000 kg car experiences a net force of 9500 N while decelerating from 30 m/s to 23.4 m/s. How far does it travel while slowing down?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE. This question is based on applying physics equations and the tag physics is for the mathematics used in solving. Moreover, it would be better if you show us what do you know about solving such problems.

Comment: Peace. Do you know the equation $x_f = x_i + v_iΔt + \frac{1}{2}a(Δt)^2$?

Answer (score 0):

You may use the formula ,

V²= U² + 2aD , where

V= final velocity , U=initial velocity , a= acceleration and D= distance traveled .

In this cases , F=9500N and mass = 100kg , therefore using F=ma , we get
a(acceleration)=9.5 m/sec²

Now out these values and you'll get the answer very easily .